# Access properties from within the object

Tags: java, oop

What is the "purist" or "correct" way to access an object's properties from within an object method that is not a getter/setter method?

```
String property = this.property;
```

or would you do:

```
String property = this.getProperty();
```

Comment: Both approaches work. Both have their advantages. It depends on the situation which to choose. Other than that, it's primarily **opinion-based**.

Comment: There are *profound*, **technical** reasons to use the `get`-method. (Surprisingly, arguing why the direct field access should be preferred is *much* harder...). Voted to reopen, although I agree that this sort of question *tends* to attract opinionated answers...

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct way. It all depends on the circumstances:

- The main reason for using `this.property` is that it removes the need for getter and setter methods. This reduces code size, which is beneficial by itself since it reduces the overall costs of debugging and maintenance.
- The main reason for using `getProperty()` is that it lets you hide data structure refactoring from the rest of the code. For example, assume that you for some reason decide to move the `property` field to an embedded object `foo`. Then you can easily redefine `getProperty()` without affecting any other code:

  `Object getProperty() { return foo.property; }`

  If you are using frameworks like JPA you can also get performance benefits from using getters and setters, since the JPA framework can perform optimizations on these that are not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

use `this.property`

The property was defined there globally so presumably you should reference it directly throughout the class.

Unless...

The `getProperty()` method transforms the property somehow AND the only intended way to access this property is via that transformation.

Generally getters are there to access a property outside the class so they should really only be used in that context.

Comment: The thing is that you can't really foresee all the changes. What seems like a good idea right now, might be regretable later. It may sound strange to resort to encapsulation inside the class itself, but implementation changes can happen. Anyway, aside from some clear cases where I know this will never happen, IMHO, I'd use accessors.

Comment: But if the public getter has behavior in it that is supposed to only run for public access to the property. For example an ID field (perhaps SSN) where the getter returns all but the last 4 digits with stars. Inside the class certainly the property should be used and not the getter.

Comment: Sure, it sounds pretty resonable and I'm sure there are other reasons to do so. I'm just saying that, in general, I'd choose the accessors :)

Comment: @Renatols ... to avoid misunderstandings with the outside world.  or even just not?

Comment: @alk I think he's talking more from the side of solving issues with refactoring. Cuspy Code's answer elaborates on that too. If one day you decide to change property to be foo.property all you would have to do is change the accessor method and the change would occur anywhere the accessor is used.

Comment: @alk, as I said, I'm sure there are plenty of reasons to choose both. I'm just not sure if I agree with "misunderstandings with the outside wolrd". There are countless implemantions of getters and setters which do nothing more than changing and returning the field's value. It's done by the sake of encapsulation; sometimes it's unecessary, sometimes it's not. Anyway, if I'm writting a getter that does nothing more than return the field's value, I might as well use it inside the class itself. After all, who can say that if its representation changes, it should not change inside the class too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use-case:

If you want the method to see/get the class' (instance's)

- *internal* representation of the its property then use the former.
- *external* representation of the property **along with the class' (instance's)  behaviour when the property is being fetched** then use the latter.